# Problems with Visual Studio and SSRS

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, db2

I'm trying to make an SSRS report for my work.  I have business intelligence, MS SQL Server 2014 and Visual Studio 2013 installed on my machine.  They are all x86, and I have the same versions as another developer that isn't having any problems with this.  I fired up VS, started the Report Wizard and entered my Data Source information.  I tested the connection and it was successful.  The next screen is the Design Query screen.  Here is the code (with a generic table name) that I used:

```
SELECT LST_NM
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE MI = 'W';
```

Just a simple query to get things rolling.  But I got the following error:

> An error occurred while the query design method was being saved. ERROR[42S02][IBM][CLIDriver][DB2/NT64] SQL0204N "CLAYBJ.TABLE_NAME" IS an undefined name.  SQLSTATE=42704

I plugged the same exact query into SqlDBx and returned a couple thousand results.  I'm using the same credentials to connect to the DB from both VS and SqlDBx.  I've found nothing helpful searching with google.  Not sure if that's because I'm getting a strange error code, or if I'm just searching for it the wrong way, but I've got nothing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-Jared

Comment: It occurs to me that I might need to clear something up.  **CLAYBJ** is my username for connecting to the DB.  Just in case anyone was wondering

Comment: And the database you're connecting to is an IBM DB2 database?

Comment: What if you fully declare the table with the Schema?  [Schema].[Table_Name]

Comment: @TabAlleman Yes, it is an IBM DB2 DB.  Sorry, I should have included that.

Comment: @BradD, I tried that too when I saw it was putting my username in with the table.  It gives me the same error, but with the Schema instead of my username

Comment: Sounds like the issue is on your DB2 server.  I changed the tags so hopefully someone who knows DB2 will see your question.